# How to add an ASP.NET MVC sub-application under Orchard CMS in IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, url-rewriting, orchardcms

I have created an orchard cms blog with a url like www.testurl.com I would like to have another sub site at the address www.testurl.com/subsite

I have added the application in IIS7 and the orchard blog works fine but when I try to access the URL: www.testurl.com/subsite

I get the following error:

> Compilation Error  Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Orchard'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 103:         Line 104:         Line 105:         Line 106:       Line 107:
>
> Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Blog\Web.config    Line: 105

can this be done? do I need to modify the Orchard site  or IIS?

thanks

Mark

Comment: I've not found a working solution to this yet, the following blog proposes a solution I tried but had other issues with, it may work for others: http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2010/04/solved-breaking-parent-webconfig.html I have managed to get a satisfactory workaround by also moving my orchard site to a sub-site and having the root URL re-direct to the new location so now all urls work as expected

Comment: did u consider making your sub MVC site a module for your Orchard main site? It is quite easy to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an URL redirect/rewrite that would handle your URL and make it point to a separate app.

You can do that twofold:

1. using the **[Orchard RewriteRules](http://orchardrewriterules.codeplex.com/)** module or
2. using the **[URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)** feature in IIS