# Can I set up Orchard CMS to be a sub directory of my "real" web site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, orchardcms, virtual-directory

I have a web site and I would like to add some CMS capabilities to it (blog, forum, comments, rss, etc...).
Ideally, I'd like to co-host my existing asp.net MVC web site with a CMS like Orchard which should be under mysite.com/cms or mysite.com/blog.

How could I set that up ?

Alternatively I suppose one could set up a sub domain such as cms.mysite.com but I'm wary of deployment complications and SEO implications. Any feedback on such scenarios ?

I suppose I could also do the other way around and have my real web site a sub directory, and have the CMS be at the root of the site. I just need to marry the two together.
I'd like to avoid URL rewriting if possible as suggested at [How to add an ASP.NET MVC sub-application under Orchard CMS in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849584/how-to-add-an-asp-net-mvc-sub-application-under-orchard-cms-in-iis7) as it can have its own complications (e.g. the application is not aware of its real url).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Orchard is not designed to add capabilities to an existing site. It needs to run in its own IIS application.